# Assignment build in functions

Tags: python

I found an example which make me curious:

```
int = float
def parse_string(s):
    return int(s)
print(parse_string('42'))
```

The returned result is `42.0`. Int and float are build in functions. How come that we can assign float to int (build in functions)? It seems to be wired to me.

Comment: you are re declaring the built in method, same as `parse_string = some_other_func`

Answer (score 1):

Python use references to objects.

When you write `int = float`, you only change the `int` reference to point to the same object (a built-in function here) than the one pointed by `float` reference.

You don't change the nature of `int` of course.

You can restore the `int` reference by importing **[__builtin__](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html)**:

```
import __builtin__

int = __builtin__.int
```